# How to restart heroku application from within the application in django

Tags: django, heroku

How can i restart the heroku application from within the website in django?

Please help.

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: yes i've a django application hosted on heroku, i want to restart my heroku app from within the application, i.e. i want to place a restart button, whenever admin clicks that button it restart the heroku app, similar to what we do on CLI (heroku restart)

Comment: Hum, I don't know if it is possible ;/

Comment: Check out there, may help you https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno